# How can I link a mesh after its modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

I would like to link a mesh with its modifiers, but can only find a way to link meshes before their modifiers are applied.

How can I link a mesh post modifier?  I would like to take the product of those modifiers, then move into a few different directions.  I've seen ways of copying modifiers around but I don't see how that wouldn't lead to a headache if I wanted to change something upstream.